# CIColor and CIFIlter: How to adjust image color, based on a given image

Tags: swift2, cifilter

I'd like to replace a portion of an image by another one. In the process, I'd like the pasted image look similar to the portion it replace in the orignal image and think I need to adapt the color of the pasted image.

How to do this? What potential CIFilter should use? Example in swift welcome.

In your opinion, does the CIColorMatrix might help as I guess, but in this case, how to get the color matrix from the original image portion?

Answer (score 3):

You need *histogram specification*. This operation takes the histogram of one image and applies it to another. Sadly, CoreImage doesn't include histogram operations, so you need to look at either Metal Performance Shaders of vImage. I'll quickly run though vImage for you ([taken from my blog](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/vimage-histogram-functions-part-ii.html))

[image]

The first step to recreate the example above is to calculate the histogram. We'll use the same technique described in [my previous post](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/histogram-functions-in-accelerate-vimage.html) to convert a supplied CGImage to a vImage buffer. However this time, we're not populating a target image, we're populating four arrays of unsigned integers that will contain the histogram values for each of the four colour channels (red, green, blue and alpha).

vImage's API shows its C roots and to calculate the histogram of inBuffer,  we initialise four arrays, create pointers to those arrays and create pointers to an array of those pointers:

```
let alpha = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let red = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let green = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
let blue = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)

let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(alpha)
let redPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(red)
let greenPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(green)
let bluePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(blue)

let rgba = [alphaPtr, redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr]

let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>>(rgba)
```

The histogram object, along with the source image, are passed to `vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(_:_:_:)`:

```
vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
```

The original arrays, alpha, red, green and blue, are now populated with the histogram data.

**Histogram Specification**

Given the histogram data, we now need to specify it against another image (the sunset in our case). In my example, I've separated these two steps into two functions and my specification function requires a histogram tuple of the form:

```
histogram: (alpha: [UInt], red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt])
```

The vImage specification function, `vImageHistogramSpecification_ARGB888(_:_:_:_:)` requires an unsafe mutable pointer to an unsafe pointer of the pixel counts for each bucket for each channel. The following code prepares histogram to pass into vImage (`vImagePixelCount` is a type alias for `Uint`):

```
let alphaPtr = UnsafePointer<vImagePixelCount>(histogram.alpha)
let redPtr = UnsafePointer<vImagePixelCount>(histogram.red)
let greenPtr = UnsafePointer<vImagePixelCount>(histogram.green)
let bluePtr = UnsafePointer<vImagePixelCount>(histogram.blue)

let rgba = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<vImagePixelCount>>([alphaPtr, redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr])
```

Using the inBuffer and outBuffer technique from the [previous post](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/histogram-functions-in-accelerate-vimage.html), we can now specify the histogram for a source image and populate a vImage buffer:

```
vImageHistogramSpecification_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, &outBuffer, rgba, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
```